# numpy random numpers in specified shape of any complexity

Tags: python, numpy, random, numbers, shapes

```
def shaperand(s):
    r = []
    for i in s:
        if type(i) in [list,tuple]:
            r.append(shaperand(i))
        else:
            r.append(np.random.rand())
    return r
```

So,

```
shaperand([[1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7]])
```

results in:

```
[[0.27611814857329864, 0.6271028191307862], [0.6245245446787084, 0.743259931401167, 0.9061663248784034], [0.7236900927531255, 0.540622773908648]]
```

I didn't see a function to do this. If there's one it'd be faster. Is there a better, more nifty way to write this?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are working with NumPy arrays, it is quite simple:

```
a = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
np.random.random(a.shape)
```

If you have lists, you could do:

```
import random

def shaperand(s):
    return [shaperand(e) if isinstance(e, list) else random.random() for e in s]
```

Comment: didn't know you could do that. Thanks!